# Increasing 3D Model fidelity with three.js from Blender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d

I am building a website using react and I imported a 3d model I made in Blender to my website using three.js. Everything is working fine, the basics of the model are ok, but it just seems like the rendering quality is not the same as in some examples I see online.
So I was wondering if there are ways to improve the model's fidelity, textures resolution and the lightning (which makes the most diference).

This is a comparasion between a scene I found online (https://henryheffernan.com/), and my current model (my model is the 2nd image).

[image]
[image]

I exported my model form blender in the .gltf format, I then generated a .js file from the .gltf file using the npx gltfjsx command.

Comment: I don't understand your logic a bit... This question is very broad, many factors are responsible for modeling and presentation. To investigate what is wrong/or can be improve, has to be two same models and a comparative difference in relation to them. If you provide two different models, both have different interpretation conditions. Show your model and the same with the quality you would like achieve. Otherwise it is difficult to estimate. It's like comparing a tractor to a bicycle. Both of them have their own structure and _drive_. To my eyes, the car looks decent...